# Model has upcased attribute – Always upcase in where queries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model

I have a model that always upcases one of its attributes (`id_tag`) when saved in the database in a before_validation action.

However, when I retrieve the model using where conditions, I have to manually upcase this attribute everywhere I query the model.

Is there a way to automatically do this so that I don't have to retype and remember this all the time?

I could probably change the models where method logic, but is this recommended?

Comment: The field is called id_tag

Comment: what database?  some default to case insensitive, some don't.  see [here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html)

Comment: do you wish to keep the value of the field in UPCASE in database?

Answer (score 0):

You could put all of the queries into methods that "hide" the fact that case matters. If all of those queries make sense to put in the model in question, you'll have the knowledge about uppercase in one place, so you won't be able to forget about it.

I'd also reassess why case matters -- if you just need it for *display*, then putting that concern in the database may not be the best idea. Not enough info to know why :)